# Most efficient way to Concat Many String if they're not empty

Tags: dataweave

Im kinda new to DataWeave and i have like 20 Strings.

These Strings may be empty or have an actual values

Payload looks like this :

```
{
    str1 : "String 1",
    str2 : "String 2",
    str3 : "",
    str4 : "String 4",
}
```

Im looking for the most efficient way to put the none Empty string between and `<li> </li>` html tag and then concatenate these Strings.

So results should look like this `<li> String 1 </li><li> String 2 </li><li> String 4 </li>`

Here's my solution :

```
var str_arr = [
         "String 1",
         "String 2",
         "",
         "String 4",
]
---
concatenated_str:  str_arr joinBy ""
```

Is there any better solution than this one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using Mule4.

A couple of ways you can get it done.  The first way below "iterates" over your data three times:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = {
    str1 : "String 1",
    str2 : "String 2",
    str3 : "",
    str4 : "String 4",
}
---
"<li>" ++ ((data pluck $ filter not isEmpty($)) joinBy "</li><li>") ++ "</li>"
```

This second way iterates over your data twice, this will be a more efficient solution:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = {
    str1 : "String 1",
    str2 : "String 2",
    str3 : "",
    str4 : "String 4",
}
---
data pluck $ reduce (e,acc="") -> acc ++ "<li>$(e)</li>" default ""
```

NOTE: I added a complete solution to your problem as compared to just using the array made up and then running `joinBy`.  But yes if you have the collection `joinBy` will be a pretty good solution.

NOTE: Change the `output` to anything you desire, I suspect `text/plain` is what you want.  I used `application/dw` because I was using the Preview to test.

Comment: application/dw should be used only for debugging. It has a performance impact.

Comment: The performance of both should be similar as filter is lazy this means it is not iterated 3 times. And for me first solution is much more clear as it describes the solution with the same terms as it was described.

Comment: Good to know @machaval!